# firebase test lab showing error The uploaded test APK does not contain the test runner class specified in the manifest file

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-test-lab, flutter-integration-test

I am getting the following error when I am testing my flutter intetration tests in test lab via sh file script in mac

**The uploaded test APK does not contain the test runner class specified in the manifest file. This is probably because the test runner isn't built into the test APK (might be in the app APK instead).**

(my flutter version is 3.13)

in default config I have this

```
            defaultConfig 
           {testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJunitRunner" }
```

and dependencies I have this
dependencies {
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'. androidTestImplementation
'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'}
this is my mainActivity under andrioidTest directory.

```
   @RunWith(FlutterTestRunner.class)
    public class MainActivityTest {
     @Rule
     public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> rule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, true, false);
```

in app mainfest I have this

```
          <instrumentation
       android:name="androidx.test.runner.AndroidJunitRunner"
       android:targetPackage="com.hello.integration"></instrumentation>
```

.sh file

```
      pushd android
      # # flutter build generates files in android/ for building the app
       flutter build apk
     ./gradlew app:assembleAndroidTest
      ./gradlew app:assembleDebug - 
     Ptarget=integration_test/app_test.dart
      popd


       gcloud firebase test android run --type instrumentation \
          --app build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk \
          --test build/app/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug- 
           androidTest.apk \
          --use-orchestrator \
          --timeout 3m \
          --results-bucket=gs://project_bucket_name \
          --results-dir=tests/firebase
```

any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything wrong based on the information posted. I think your best option is to reach out to the Firebase Test Lab team via their Slack channel #test-lab at https://firebase.community/ and post the Matrix ID of one of your runs that shows this problem.

Comment: sure @Maik,Thank you.by the way where can we find matrix id? I am new to test lab.

Comment: I am not able to find any matrix id  in my testlab console and I have added .sh file for the reference in the question .I have already raised a question in  slack but still no luck